# New to ASP, trying to use a tokenizer

Tags: asp.net, tokenize

Sorry for the kind of noob question but having issues trying to get a Tokenizer working. Tried [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vbscript/tokenize.aspx) example but on the line of the Tokenize() I get an error Type mismatched. I've also tried to use Split with a very similar outcome.

The server is using IIS and is pretty old if that helps at all. Sorry, never used asp / .net before.

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got it with Split(), The problem might have been more the line after but the error code wasn't very helpful.